# Optimal performance Remote Desktop Linux -> Windows

Tags: linux

I have Raspberry PI2 with Ubuntu Mate and xfreerdp installed and it works like a terminal, remoting to a my working machine with Windows. The problem is that the performance is not very good and it is not because of the hardware or network latency.

When I use windows -> windows with RDP 8.0 it runs over UDP and the experience is very good. I searched a lot and I can't find linux RDP client that support RDP over UDP. Currently I am looking for *FREE* alternative of RDP that can run over UDP and deliver similar experience like RDP 8.0.